# Camera not Working

Tags: root-access, camera

Since a couple of days, my brand new Sony Xperia M2 (less than a week old) now has the error message '"unfortunatly, camera has stopped' every time i try to use the camera.

I've googled, and even tried "reset to factory", but nothing worked so far.

Of note: the device was rooted with "towelroot".

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue at Android 4.4.1 KitKat with the camera.

Try another camera-app instead and see if it's an Android Problem.

When the other App is working, i recommend to upgrade to 4.4.3 with the fix for this.

Comment: Android Version says it's 4.3, Model D2303, Kernel 3.4.0+, Build 18.0.C.1.13.
I'll try installing another camera app.